# The value of property is in HTML String coming from API (REACTJS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, dom

[SEE IMAGE HERE!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl7Wv.png)

how can i show this html in UI! please help

```
<div class="photo"><img width="40px" height="40px" src="http://localhost/castclass/public/uploads/user_35579/user_35571/"></div>
<div class="action-area">
<span class="name">Something</span>
<span>Join Request for Something</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use this `message` as a component itself.

Comment: @Fakhir Arslan Welcome to SO. Please consider adding more details to your answer  - Like why to think so, how to etc. Thanks .